# Illegal string offset on heroku deployment

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, heroku, laravel-5.4

I am configuring my postgresql driver in Laravel 5.4 for deployment to Heroku. Here is my config/database.php, the `default` is already set to `pgsql`

```
'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))['host'],
        'database' => substr(parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))['path'], 1),
        'username' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL")['username']),
        'password' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL")['password']),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
    ],
```

When I commit I see this warning

```
PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in app/config/database.php on line 62
```

When run `heroku run php artisan serve`I am getting an error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
Type error: PDO::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

Here is my `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration array should look like the following if you want to get correct data from the .env provided.

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this site. It caters also mysql, and sqlite, please read
https://mattstauffer.co/blog/installing-a-laravel-app-on-heroku